# How to get click event on a new created row with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a `table` :

```
<table id="myTable" style="cursor :pointer;">
 <tr>
   <td>col 1</td><td>col2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>field</td><td>Field 2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>another field</td><td>one more field</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

when I click on a `row` this code add a new `row` :

```
$("#myTable tr").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
   var value=$(this).find('td:eq(1)').html();
   if (value) {
   alert('adding New Row !')
   $('#myTable').find('tbody:last').append('<tr><td>new Field</td><td>New Field</td></tr>');
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s0h9mwms/)

But now when I click on the new created `row` nothing append.
Why another `row`is not created ?

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** instead:

```
$("#myTable").on('click','tr',function() {});
```

Comment: 100 points in 5 minutes for the same answer on two questions :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: OMG. wasnt expecting 7(7 when commenetd) upvotes for this :P.  i didn't posted this answer in other one though. kept it as comment. :)